# Connect Vb.net 2012 to Mysql (select, insert, update, delete)

Tags: vb.net

I want to create a vb.net application with a login.
I want that the login verify the username and password with a table witch contains all usernames and passwords of all members and if the login found a correspondence with the table, I want that the login connect the user at the application.
In the next form, I want that the application show some 'informations' like Name, E-mail, ... for the user that is logged in.
I have try a lot of code, but none was working correctly.

**The imports statements is underligned in green. VB.net 2012 does not accept.
Dim myConnection As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection(): here MySqlConnection is underligned blue**

here is part of my code:

Imports System.Data
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class Sign_in

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Me.Dispose()
End Sub


Public Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    'Declare variables
    Dim pwd, username As String
    'Get credentials variables
    username = Me.username.Text
    pwd = Me.TextBox2.Text


    Dim myConnection As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection()
    Dim myConnectionString As String = "Server=localhost;Database=mayombe_mdcs;Uid=root;Pwd=;"
    myConnection.ConnectionString = myConnectionString
    myConnection.Open()
```

Comment: There is no magic control you can use to do all this for you. You need to write it yourself. Also, you need to ask separate questions for each issue you are having so you can be assisted with each of them. We are not here to program for you, but to help you when you need assistance on a specific issue.

Comment: "What can I do for make this 'simple' application?" You can learn programming.

Comment: @Hoh Believe me, Im learning

Comment: @Steve Im going to post it soon

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you either haven't installed the MySQL connector, or you've installed it but haven't added a reference to it to your project. VB won't talk to a MySQL database unless you have the connector installed and referenced.

Download and install the MySQL Connector from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/).

You now need to add a reference to this in your project:

[image]

Select *Browse* and navigate to the *Assemblies* directory for the MySQL Connector:

[image]

Select *MySQL.Data.dll* and click Ok:

[image]

Now all you need to do is add `Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient` to the very top of your form code and you will be able to access your database once you have created the correct connection string.